# Some windows 'visually freezing' in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, freeze

For the last few months I have been occasionally using TeamViewer to access a PC running Ubuntu 18.04. To achieve that the said PC has been left turned on and ideally I would like to keep it this way, so no remedy in the form of restarting is possible.

I am connected just now and am noticing some rather weird behaviour. Some of the applications seem to freeze either momentarily after starting or some time into using them. What is puzzling is that they are only 'visually unresponsive' - they still respond to mouse and keyboard input and only what is displayed in a window is frozen. I can easily close the window and the process immediately stops. When I run it again, I can see that the changes due to mouse and keyboard input have been registered. Also, in the particular instance of File Manager (Nautilus), when it is 'frozen' and I click to change the folder being viewed, the taskbar registers the change (the name of the folder I am in is changed). The particular two apps that are worst affected are gnome-control-center and gnome-system-monitor. On the other hand, some apps seem to never be affected, e.g. Firefox.

I have very limited knowledge of Ubuntu, so I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain what is going on. Presumably there is a process responsible for what is 'visually shown' which ideally I should kill and restart and everything should get back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be much easier to solve than I thought. A simple Alt+F2 and 'r' command restarted the gnome shell and all the problems were gone, while keeping the TeamViewer session on.  However I am still a bit curious why the weird 'visual-only' freezing took place, so if anybody ever bothers to provide some insight I will be very grateful.